# Dashboards for Development Metrics

Tags: dashboard

I need a private, host my own, behind-a-firewall dashboard like Geckoboard or Ducksboard.

Widgets for Atlassian products, Git, Junit based results and Splunk would be ideal.

More context-
Geckoboard and Ducksboard look great to me, but my Atlassian products, Git, etc. are all behind a firewall.  Opening up the firewall for Geckoboard, Ducksboard, etc. is not an option.

I know they both have APIs where I could push data to, but I don't really want to write custom REST calls for aforementioned products.

Know of any similar dashboards where I can install locally?

Answer (score 2):

You can check out Dashing http://shopify.github.io/dashing/

It's a dashboard written by the guys from Shopify, written in Ruby.

You can see the list of widgets it supports in the link below, though I know it doesn't really cover what you are after. But you should be able to write your own widgets.

https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/wiki/Additional-Widgets

I've only played around it for a little bit, but seems quite easy to get started.